# How to use a custom mode with ng2-ace-editor?

Tags: angular, ace-editor

I'm working with ng2-ace-editor component in an angular5 project where i use a custom music notation with specific highlight rules.  I know i can pass an object to the mode parameter but i can't figure out what to set it to in order to use my own mode.

For the record i set up and tested my own mode using ace-build following the steps below and it works like a charm.
- forked ace-builds [here](https://github.com/GGracieux/cnb-ace-builds)
- added "cnb" mode definition (src-noconflict/mode-cnb.js)
- added an entry for "cnb" mode in supportedModes array (src-noconflict/ext-modelist.js)
- switched to "cnb" mode in editor.html sample

Comment: share code and more details please.